# Transfering my DataBase over the internet on port 80

Tags: sql, sql-injection

I was reading an article about Sql injection in the article the author mentioned that if an sql injection attack has been performed the attacker can transfer an entire database over port 80 my question is how can you transfer your database over the http port is  there any software to do it ? how can i protect myself over hijacking my database

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh580736.aspx
```

**Transfer an entire database over port 80**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My guess is that if you got somewhere can be injected, then they can probably make it via following steps:

> 1. Backup the DB in SQL or script out all data into a file
> 2. Using some DBMS function copy that file to web server so that expose to internet, like xp_cmdshell in SQL Server
> 3. Download it via your web server

Comment: That's probably not how it's done and would require far more than an SQL injection attack.

Answer (score 0):

An SQL injection means you have a weakness in your code - usually your web code which explains the port 80 - that allows a third party to run any SQL commands they want on your database. If you have left yourself open to this then you can't prevent them from doing whatever they want.

The ways to avoid it depend on the specific language you are programming in (Python, Ruby, Java, etc) but the two main points are you want to properly "sanitize your inputs - that is make sure characters are properly escaped so someone can't throw in a semicolon and wreak havoc, for example - and parameterize your queries. This means when you write your SQL queries you use parameters for user defined input and then safely fill those parameters. In Perl you would use:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE id = ?");

$sth->execute($id);
```

Think of them as place holders.

Again the exact method for this depends on your language of choice.

When you understand this you are on your way: http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 0):

**There is absolutely no point in taking such measures.**

This is just one out of **billions** possible exploits allowed by **one** vulnerability. So, it'll be like filling holes in a sieve - a toilsome and quite useless work as if you leave only one exploit open - it will be used.

Instead of that just secure your site against SQL injection.